# Why does it work to store CPUID results in an int array and pass to printf "%s"?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, cpuid

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int index = 0;
    int reg[3];
    __asm__(
        "cpuid \n\t"
        : "=b"(reg[0]), "=c"(reg[2]), "=d"(reg[1])
            // editor's note: CPUID also modifies EAX; this buggy code doesn't tell the compiler about it
        : "a"(index)); 
    printf("%s\n",&reg);
}
```

Why does int is treated as string.I need some help to explain me why is it like that.

Comment: The `printf` call invokes *undefined behavior* - and your compiler should be warning you about it

Comment: Consult an instruction set reference. The `cpuid` packs the string into 3 registers. Note you should really use a fixed length format for that.

Comment: So what should i do to fix it :)

Comment: It prints correct answer

Comment: And why is 3x4 chars saved in array of ints

Comment: @smartalec “prints the correct answer” doesn't mean that your code is correct.  You can fix this e.g. using a union: `union { int reg[3]; char str[12]; } id;` then, use a fixed length format like `%12s` to work around the lack of NUL-termination.

Comment: @smartalec And as Jester said: cpuid is specified to work like this.  If you want to know why, ask Intel.  I suppose it's an easy way to return a short string from an interface normally used to return bitmasks and integers.

Comment: So these registers returns integer or what ? :) i m confused :)

Comment: @fuz You should make that an answer.

Comment: Your code is buggy: you forgot to tell the compiler that your `asm` statement modifies EAX.  Using `"+a"(index)` as an in/out operand would be an easy way to do that.

Comment: @zwol Eric Postpischil's answer already addresses all relevant issues.  Feel free to accept his.

Answer (score 3):

When zero is given in `eax`, the `cpuid` instruction returns two things:

- in `eax`<sup>1</sup>, the maximum value supported for the input operand in `eax` for `cpuid` on this processor, and
- in `ebx`, `edx`, and `eax`, the string “GenuineIntel”, distributed across those registers in that order. The bytes of the string are simply put in the registers, four bytes in each register.

The assembly code you have shown causes the GCC or Clang compiler to copy the latter registers to your `reg` array.

To print this array correctly, you could pass to `printf`:

- a format string containing `%.12s` to print at most 12 characters, and
- a `char *` that points to the first byte of `reg`.

For example:

```
printf("%.12s\n", (char *) reg);
```

(Note that this conversion to `char *` is specifically allowed by C aliasing rules: The bytes of any object may be accessed using a pointer-to-character type. Other pointer conversions, or uses of their results, are not always defined by the C standard. Pedantically, `(char *) &reg` may be needed, as it provides a pointer to the first byte of the entire array rather than a pointer to the first byte of `reg[0]`. A strict interpretation of the C standard could say that the latter pointer is not reliable for arithmetic beyond `reg[0]`.)

---

**Footnote 1:** Modifying an input-only operand is a bug; the compiler will assume that EAX is unmodified across the `asm` statement.  In this case, that could lead to calling printf with `al != 0`, even though there are no floating-point values in XMM registers.  (x86-64 System V calling convention.)  With other callers / surrounding code, the problems could be more serious.

Since you don't care about the value of `index` after your asm statement, a [read/write `"+a"`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html#Modifiers) operand is an easy way in this case to tell the compiler that EAX is also modified:

```
    int index = 0;
    int reg[3];
    __asm__(
        "cpuid"
        : "+a"(index), "=b"(reg[0]), "=c"(reg[2]), "=d"(reg[1])
        );
```